# ChartJS memory usage

Tags: php, chart.js, out-of-memory

So I've experienced some problems with one of my PHP pages using ChartJS, when I load my charts (Pie/Bar), with a good amount of data, then the google tab on revisit can not respond / say `out of memory` or something like that. I've read that it should be possible to make ChartJS be garbage-collected by calling `.destroy()`, but that removes my chart, so I don't know how that should be done?

Is there a proper way to create a chart, and then do some kind of clean-up after, and still show the chart on the webpage?

This is the function for barChart

```php
**function barChart(barChartVal) {

    const color = new chartColor();
    new Chart(document.getElementById("chart-area-last-5-runs"), {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            labels: [barChartVal[5][0], barChartVal[5][1], barChartVal[5][2], barChartVal[5][3], barChartVal[5][4]],
            datasets: [{
                data: [barChartVal[0][0], barChartVal[0][1], barChartVal[0][2], barChartVal[0][3], barChartVal[0][4]],
                label: 'Passed',
                backgroundColor: color.green(),
            }, {
                data: [barChartVal[1][0], barChartVal[1][1], barChartVal[1][2], barChartVal[1][3], barChartVal[1][4]],
                label: 'Failed',
                backgroundColor: color.red(),
            }, {
                data: [barChartVal[2][0], barChartVal[2][1], barChartVal[2][2], barChartVal[2][3], barChartVal[2][4]],
                label: 'Error',
                backgroundColor: color.yellow(),
            }, {
                data: [barChartVal[3][0], barChartVal[3][1], barChartVal[3][2], barChartVal[3][3], barChartVal[3][4]],
                label: 'Not Run',
                backgroundColor: color.blue(),
            }, {
                data: [barChartVal[4][0], barChartVal[4][1], barChartVal[4][2], barChartVal[4][3], barChartVal[4][4]],
                label: 'Not Applicable',
                backgroundColor: color.black(),
            }]
        },
        options: {
            scales: {
                xAxes: [{
                    stacked: true,
                    ticks: {
                        display: false //this will remove only the label
                    }
                }],
                yAxes: [{ stacked: true }]
            },
            tooltips: {
                /* tooltip text made smaller to longer labels fit */
                mode: 'index',
                intersect: false,
                titleFontSize: 14,
                bodyFontSize: 13,
                bodySpacing: 0,
                titleSpacing: 0,
                xPadding: 2,
                yPadding: 2,
                cornerRadius: 2,
                titleMarginBottom: 2
            },
            hover: {
                mode: 'index',
                intersect: false
            },
            animation: false, //No animations
            parsing: false,
            normalized: true
        }
    });
}**
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do something like that, you can transform the chart to an image and display that, then you can delete your chart which will free up the memory. Downside of this will be that its not interactable anymore:

```js
const options = {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        backgroundColor: 'orange'
      },
      {
        label: '# of Points',
        data: [7, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
        backgroundColor: 'pink'
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    animation: false
  }
}

const ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
const chartContainer = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer');
const chartImage = document.getElementById('chartImage');
const chart = new Chart(ctx, options);
const base64Chart = chart.toBase64Image();

// Set image source to chart image
chartImage.src = base64Chart;

// Destroy chart and remove canvas
chart.destroy();
chartContainer.remove();
```

```html
<body>
  <img id="chartImage">
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.js"></script>
</body>
```